# When to use "а ведь", as opposed to "хотя/хоть"

Tags: словоупотребление

> Она больше не знает, что к чему, **а ведь** ей почти  всегда это было понятно.

I'm wondering when it is preferable to use "а ведь" to show contrast.

> Она больше не знает, что к чему, **хотя** ей почти  всегда это было понятно.
>
> Она больше не знает, что к чему, **хоть** ей почти  всегда это было понятно.

Comment: **а ведь** is more emphatic and has an overtone of slight rebuke or disappointment and a kind of disbelief 'how so?', **хоть/я** is neutral

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка What about in terms of register?

Comment: they're equal and both equally usable in spoken and literary language, but not always interchangeable due to difference in emotiveness

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка А "Хотя ..." subordinate clause can also be a standalone incomplete sentence to show contrast as an afterthought, toning down what is said in a previous sentence.As for "а ведь", on the other hand, can it only be used in a complete sentence with a main and a  subordinate clause?

Comment: yes it can, when the thought suddenly hits you after some pause

Comment: imo, А ведь is a bit more colloquial, it's quite EMOTIONAL, хотя is quite neutral and generally emotionless. Хотя is a bit posher, a ведь - more 'proletarian' - forgive non-linguistic associations

Comment: it must be observed though that хотя и хоть are not always interchangable, хоть can be used in proverbs, emotional speech.

Answer (score 3):

*А ведь* conveys the larger degree of emotional involvement in the contrast between the main clause and the concessive clause:

> Она больше не знает, что к чему, хотя ей почти всегда это было понятно. // She used to understand how the things work, and now she doesn't anymore
>
> Она больше не знает, что к чему, а ведь ей почти всегда это было понятно. // She doesn't understand how the things work anymore, and I'm somehow emotional about that because she used to.

When people are talking about emotionally charged subjects, they're more likely to use *а ведь*:

> Он умирает от рака, а ведь он такой молодой! // (This is unfair!)
>
> Он умирает от рака, хотя он такой молодой. // (This is a plain statement of facts)

When people are talking about neutral subjects, they're more likely to use *хотя*:

> Алюминий стоит довольно дорого, хотя это один из самых распространённых элементов в земной коре // (This is something you would see in a textbook)
>
> Алюминий стоит довольно дорого, а ведь это один из самых распространённых элементов в земной коре // (This is something the author cares about for some reason and they want to show how emotional are they about this)